# Can i make microinstance from AMI created from small Instance in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am currently uisng Amazon Ec2 micro instance to make my server ready so that i can shift to small instance when everything is ok.

Now as `RAM` is very less in `micro instance` , I am not able to install few things which i need to install.

I can update now to small instance but i was thinking that once i ahve all ready on micro instance then i will make `AMI` from there so that i case i need to run future microinstances for some tetsing then i can use those and close them when i don't need.

Now i want to ask that if i upgrade to `small instance`. then create `AMI` from it. Then can i make `microinstance` from that `AMI or EBS Snapshot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once AMI has created , from that AMI you can launch any instance type .

Comment: You can create an AMI from an m1.small and run it on a t1.micro as long as you were running an EBS boot instance and create an EBS boot AMI.  The t1.micro instance type cannot run an instance-store AMI.

Comment: To add to Eric's comment: the newer t2.micro, t2.small, and t2.medium instances (highly recommended for this sort of temporary scenario) also support only EBS storage.